# Mongoose .find Query doesn't return collection data

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following code to get all the data from a collection:

```
app.get('/',  (req, res) => {
   Question.find({}, (err, found) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(found)
        res.send(found);
    } else {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus("Some error occured!")
    } 
  }).clone().catch(err => console.log("Error occured -- " + err));
});
```

Using debug, I'm seeing that I'm connected to my database and also that I'm sending the appropriate query:

```
Mongoose: TopicsDB.find({}, { projection: {} })
```

However, none of the data from the collection is being returned.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? It might be the case that your collection is empty.

Comment: I don't get any error messages and I've added in 5 entries into my collection

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are not using async and await in your call to the database. Every call to the database is by default an asynchronous call and hence it needs to have async and await for it to work properly.

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  await Question.find({}, (err, found) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(found)
        res.send(found);
    } else {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus("Some error occured!")
    } 
  }).clone().catch(err => console.log("Error occured -- " + err));
});
```

Try this. Hope it helps.